# How to create a Folder in C-drive directory

Tags: uwp

I know how to create a folder in the application like below:

```
  // Get the app's local folder.
   StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

string desiredName = "Subfolder";
StorageFolder newFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(desiredName,CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
```

But how to create a folder in C:\ ?

```
 string path = @"c:\MyFolder";           
 StorageFolder mainFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
```

The above is not working.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: What is not working, what exception you get? As for UWP and creating folders - you have to have a permission to manipulate folder - in this case you don't have automatic permission to `C:` - user has to grand you access. The best I think would be to use *FolderPicker*.

Comment: I had added the permission. But what I need to create a folder ?

Comment: How have you added the permission? AFAIK it's not possible to add permission to direct access a drive without omitting user.

Comment: I can access the Folder in C-Drive. Now, I need to create a folder. what are the ways to create a folder assuming access rights is granted.

Comment: If you have a *StorageFolder*, then to create new one inside, use *yourStorageFolder.CreateFolderAsync()* method.

Comment: The Folder I can access is manually created; open Document folder with file explorer, then use Add folder menu. Now I need to create a new folder using storageFolder. This windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder cannot be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how to create a folder in C:\ ?

To create a folder in `C:\`, you need to use [FolderPicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get the folder. Then use [StorageFolder.CreateFolderAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227257.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) to create a folder:

```
var picker=new  Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".exe");//add any extension to avoid exception
var folder=await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (folder != null)
{
   var myNewFolder=await folder.CreateFolderAsync("myNewFolder");
}
```

You can save the folder in the [FutureAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and in the future, you can create subfolders without a picker:

```
Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
```

Get the folder without picker:

```
var folder = await Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("PickedFolderToken");
if (folder != null)
{
    var newFolder=folder.CreateFolderAsync("myQuiteFolder");
}
```

Here is the Demo: [SaveFolderSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/SaveFolderSample).

Comment: So happy to see this solution. Give some time to test. So many features to learn for UWP. This is exciting feature that help me to save csv file into folder that user required.